# Trouble writing entire lines of string to file

Tags: c++, string, file, concatenation

Alright guys! Having an issue with writing to a file.  Basically, my problem is that when I am writing to the file, for example an address such as `2913 Harvey Drive` in the variable `person.address1` would be written in the file on separate lines instead of one line.  I need them on one line. I did some research and couldn't find anything that I understood so I was hoping that I could have an example as it relates to my code to help me understand. Here is my code:

```
int newEntry()
{
string str;
Client person;
char response;
double temp1;
double temp2;
ostringstream strs1;
ostringstream strs2;

//create file object and open file
fstream customer("customer.dat", ios:: out | ios::app);

if (!customer)
{
    cout << "Error opening file. Program aborting." << endl;
}

do
{
    cout << "Enter client information:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Name:               ";
    cin  >> person.name;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Address 1:          ";
    cin  >> person.address1;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Address 2:          ";
    cin  >> person.address2;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Phone:              ";
    cin  >> person.phone;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Acct. Balance:      ";
    cin  >> temp1;
    strs1 << temp1;
    str = strs1.str();
    person.acctBal = str;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Last Payment:       ";
    cin  >> temp2;
    strs2 << temp2;
    str = strs2.str();
    person.lastPay = str;
    cout << endl;

    customer << person.name << endl;
    customer << person.address1 << endl;
    customer << person.address2 << endl;
    customer << person.phone << endl;
    customer << person.acctBal << endl;
    customer << person.lastPay << endl;
    customer << endl;       //blank space in file

    cout << endl << "Do you want to enter another record? (Enter Y for Yes, N 
                             for No):   ";
    cin  >> response;
    //add validation to make sure they enter y or n
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << BORDER << endl << endl;


} while (toupper(response) == 'Y');

customer.close();

return 1;
}
```

I saw something on concatenating a string variable then saving the ENTIRE string variable to the file, but I'm not sure if I would understand how to read each line back either. Here is the function that reads the code:

```
int displayAll()
{
vector<Client> store;
string space;
Client foo;
int i = 0;

fstream customer("customer.dat", ios::in);

if (!customer)
{
    cout << "Error opening file. Program aborting." << endl;
    return 0;
}

while (!customer.eof())
{
    store.push_back(foo);

    customer >> store[i].name;
    customer >> store[i].address1;
    customer >> store[i].address2;
    customer >> store[i].phone;
    customer >> store[i].acctBal;
    customer >> store[i].lastPay;
    customer >> space;

    i++;
}

for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
{
    cout << "   Name:               " << store[k].name << endl
         << "   Address 1:          " << store[k].address1 << endl
         << "   Address 2:          " << store[k].address2 << endl
         << "   Phone:              " << store[k].phone << endl
         << "   Acct. Balance:      " << store[k].acctBal << endl
         << "   Last Payment:       " << store[k].lastPay << endl << endl;
}

cout << BORDER << endl << endl;

customer.close();
return 1;

}
```

So if I, for example, used a concatenating method such as:

`string += person.name;
string += newLine; //newLine would be a variable holding the endl function
string += person.address;`

(I am not sure if I understand the above code and how it works, however, or if I even did it right.)
and then saved that `string` variable to the file, would `customer >> store[i].name` store the entire line or just until there is a white space?

Comment: If you want to read a whole line as the address, then (a) make sure you read the newline after the previous field, and (b) use `getline(cin, line)` to read the line.  Also, you should be checking each and every one of those input operations.  You might consider using only line input and then parsing the resulting string via a string stream into the target variables — the C++ analogue to `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` in C.

Answer (score 0):

input string using whilte space :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char string [256];
 printf ("Insert your full address: ");
 gets (string);     // warning: unsafe (see fgets instead)
 printf ("Your address is: %s\n",string);
 return 0;
```

}

concate String Like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 int main ()
{
char str[80];
strcpy (str,"these ");
strcat (str,"strings ");
strcat (str,"are ");
strcat (str,"concatenated.");
puts (str);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: so would `outputFile << string` from your first example save the entire string including the white spaces into one line? and than would something as simple as `inputFile >> string` read the entire line?

Comment: Tried it, and it isn't yielding any `string` variable's contents.

Comment: Don't even think of using `gets()` — it is lethal to robust programs as the program cannot protect itself from abuse.  It is no longer a part of Standard C.  It has no place in a C++ program whatsoever.